# Redis protocol implementation by Kotlin

Tags: redis, kotlin

I have created my first project on the github. It is Redis client protocol implementation (request-responce part only). I would like to make my sources more Kotlin style. Please, check my sources and give me some advices.

[KRedis. Redis protocol implementation by Kotlin](https://github.com/sibircevs/kredis)

### Reply.kt

```
package redis.protocol.reply

import java.nio.charset.Charset

enum class ReplyType {
    STATUS, ERROR, INT, BULK, MULTIBULK
}

open class Reply(val bytes: ByteArray, val type: ReplyType)

class StatusReply(bytes: ByteArray) : Reply(bytes, ReplyType.STATUS) {
    companion object {
        val MARKER: Char = '+'
    }

    constructor(data: String) : this(data.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))

    fun asString(): String = String(bytes, Charsets.UTF_8)
    override fun toString(): String = "StatusReply(${asString()})"
}

class ErrorReply(bytes: ByteArray) : Reply(bytes, ReplyType.ERROR) {
    companion object {
        val MARKER: Char = '-'
    }

    constructor(data: String) : this(data.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))

    fun asString(): String = String(bytes, Charsets.UTF_8)
    override fun toString(): String = "ErrorReply(${asString()})"
}

class IntegerReply(bytes: ByteArray) : Reply(bytes, ReplyType.INT) {
    companion object {
        val MARKER: Char = ':'
    }

    constructor(data: String) : this(data.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))

    fun asString(): String = String(bytes, Charsets.UTF_8)
    @Throws(NumberFormatException::class)
    fun asLong(): Long = asString().toLong()
    @Throws(NumberFormatException::class)
    fun asInt(): Int = asString().toInt()
    override fun toString(): String = "IntegerReply(${asString()})"
}

open class BulkReply(bytes: ByteArray) : Reply(bytes, ReplyType.BULK) {
    companion object {
        val MARKER: Char = '$'
    }

    fun asByteArray(): ByteArray = bytes
    fun asAsciiString(): String = String(bytes, Charsets.US_ASCII)
    fun asUTF8String(): String = String(bytes, Charsets.UTF_8)
    fun asString(charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8): String = String(bytes, charset)
    override fun toString(): String = "BulkReply(${asUTF8String()})"
}

class NullBulkString() : BulkReply(byteArrayOf()) {
    override fun toString(): String = "NullBulkString()"
}

class MultiBulkReply(replies: List<Reply>) : Reply(byteArrayOf(), ReplyType.MULTIBULK) {
    companion object {
        val MARKER: Char = '*'
    }
    private val _replies: List<Reply>

    init {
        _replies = replies
    }

    fun asReplyList(): List<Reply> = _replies
    @Throws(IllegalArgumentException::class)
    fun asStringList(charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8): List<String> {
        if (_replies.isEmpty()) return listOf<String>()

        val strings = mutableListOf<String>()
        for (reply in _replies) {
            when(reply) {
                is StatusReply -> strings.add(reply.asString())
                is IntegerReply -> strings.add(reply.asString())
                is BulkReply -> strings.add(reply.asString(charset))
                else -> IllegalArgumentException("Could not convert " + reply + " to a string")
            }
        }
        return strings
    }
    override fun toString(): String = "MultiBulkReply(replies count = ${_replies.size})"
}
```

### RedisProtocol.kt

```
package redis.protocol

import redis.protocol.reply.Reply
import redis.protocol.reply.StatusReply
import redis.protocol.reply.ErrorReply
import redis.protocol.reply.IntegerReply
import redis.protocol.reply.BulkReply
import redis.protocol.reply.NullBulkString
import redis.protocol.reply.MultiBulkReply

import java.io.BufferedInputStream
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.io.EOFException
import java.io.IOException
import java.net.Socket

class RedisProtocol(bis: BufferedInputStream, os: OutputStream) {
    private val _is: BufferedInputStream
    private val _os: OutputStream
    companion object {
        val CR = 13.toByte()
        val LF = 10.toByte()
        val NEWLINE = byteArrayOf(13, 10)
    }

    init {
        _is = bis
        _os = os
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    constructor(socket: Socket) : this(BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()), BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()))

    @Throws(IOException::class, EOFException::class)
    fun receive(): Reply {
        val code: Int = _is.read()

        if (code == -1) {
            throw EOFException()
        }
        when (code) {
            StatusReply.MARKER.toInt() -> {
                return StatusReply(readSimpleElement())
            }
            ErrorReply.MARKER.toInt() -> {
                return ErrorReply(readSimpleElement())
            }
            IntegerReply.MARKER.toInt() -> {
                return IntegerReply(readSimpleElement())
            }
            BulkReply.MARKER.toInt() -> {
                val (size, bytes) = readBytes()
                if (size == -1)
                    return NullBulkString()
                else
                    return BulkReply(bytes)
            }
            MultiBulkReply.MARKER.toInt() -> {
                val size = String(readSimpleElement()).toInt()
                val replies: List<Reply> = (1..size).map { receive() }.toList()
                return MultiBulkReply(replies)
            }
            else -> throw IOException("Unexpected character in stream: " + code)
        }
    }

    fun send(msg: ByteArray): Unit {
        _os.write(msg)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun readSimpleElement(): ByteArray = ByteArrayOutputStream().use { boas ->
        for (b: Byte in _is) {
            if (b == CR) {
                val lf = _is.iterator().next() // Remove byte LF from stream
                if (lf == LF)
                    break
                else
                    throw IOException("String that cannot contain a CR or LF character (no newlines are allowed).")
            } else {
                boas.write(b.toInt())
            }
        }
        boas.toByteArray()
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class, NumberFormatException::class, IllegalArgumentException::class)
    private fun readBytes(): Pair<Int, ByteArray> {
        val size = String(readSimpleElement()).toInt()

        if (size > Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Supports arrays up to ${Integer.MAX_VALUE -8 } in size")
        }
        if (size == -1)
            return Pair(-1, byteArrayOf())
        if (size < 0)
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid size: " + size)

        var total = 0
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        if (size > 0) // For correct "$0\r\n\r\n" processing
            for (b: Byte in _is) {
                baos.write(b.toInt())
                total += 1
                if (total == size) break
            }
        val bytes = baos.toByteArray()
        baos.close()
        val cr: Int = _is.read()
        val lf: Int = _is.read()
        if (bytes.size != size) {
            throw IOException("Wrong size $size. Bytes have been read: ${bytes.size}")
        }        
        if (cr != CR.toInt() || lf != LF.toInt()) {
            throw IOException("Improper line ending: $cr, $lf")
        }
        return Pair(size, bytes)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class, EOFException::class)
    fun receiveAsync(): Reply {
        synchronized (_is) {
            return receive()
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun sendAsync(msg: ByteArray) {
        synchronized (_os) {
            send(msg)
        }
        _os.flush()
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun close() {
        _is.close()
        _os.close()
    }
}
```

### Command.kt

```
package redis.client

import redis.protocol.RedisProtocol
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

enum class InsertType {
    BEFORE, AFTER
}

private fun ByteArrayOutputStream.writeAsBulkString(bytes: ByteArray) {
    val size: Int = bytes.size
    val strSize: String = size.toString()
    this.write('$'.toInt())
    this.write(strSize.toByteArray(), 0, strSize.length)
    this.write(RedisProtocol.NEWLINE, 0, 2)
    this.write(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
    this.write(RedisProtocol.NEWLINE, 0, 2)
}

private fun ByteArrayOutputStream.writeAsBulkString(value: Int) {
    this.writeAsBulkString(value.toString().toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
}

private fun ByteArrayOutputStream.writeAsBulkString(vararg values: String) {
    for (value in values) {
        this.writeAsBulkString(value.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
    }
}

private fun ByteArrayOutputStream.writeAsArrayStart(arraySize: Int) {
    val sArraySize = arraySize.toString()
    this.write('*'.toInt())
    this.write(sArraySize.toByteArray(), 0, sArraySize.length)
    this.write(RedisProtocol.NEWLINE, 0, 2)
}

private fun singleCommand(cmdName: String): Command {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val cmd = baos.use {
        val size = 1 // komanda
        baos.writeAsArrayStart(size)
        baos.writeAsBulkString(cmdName)
        baos.toByteArray()
    }
    return Command(cmdName, cmd)
}

private fun oneParamCommand(cmdName: String, param: ByteArray): Command {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val cmd = baos.use {
        val size = 2 // komanda + param
        baos.writeAsArrayStart(size)
        baos.writeAsBulkString(cmdName)
        baos.writeAsBulkString(param)
        baos.toByteArray()
    }
    return Command(cmdName, cmd)
}

private fun twoParamCommand(cmdName: String, param1: ByteArray, param2: ByteArray): Command {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val cmd = baos.use {
        val size = 3 // komanda + param
        baos.writeAsArrayStart(size)
        baos.writeAsBulkString(cmdName)
        baos.writeAsBulkString(param1)
        baos.writeAsBulkString(param2)
        baos.toByteArray()
    }
    return Command(cmdName, cmd)
}

public fun cmdAppend(key: String, value: String): Command = cmdAppend(key.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8), value.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
public fun cmdAppend(key: ByteArray, value: ByteArray): Command = twoParamCommand(Command.APPEND, key, value)

public fun cmdAuth(password0: String): Command = oneParamCommand(Command.AUTH, password0.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))

class Command(val name: String, val cmd: ByteArray) {

    companion object Factory {
        val APPEND: String = "APPEND" // Append a value to a key; Available since 2.0.0.
        val AUTH: String = "AUTH" // Authenticate to the server
...
    }
}
```

### RedisClient.kt

```
package redis.client

import redis.protocol.RedisProtocol
import redis.protocol.reply.*

import java.net.Socket
import java.io.IOException

class RedisClient(val host: String, val port: Int, val db: Int, val passwd: String) {
    lateinit var redisProtocol: RedisProtocol

    constructor(host: String, port: Int, db: Int) : this(host, port, db, "")
    constructor(host: String, port: Int) : this(host, port, 0, "")

    @Throws(RedisException::class)
    fun connect(): Boolean {
        try {
            redisProtocol = RedisProtocol(Socket(host, port))
            if (passwd != "")
                execute { cmdAuth(passwd) } // RedisException will be thrown if the ErrorReply occurs
            if (db != 0)
                execute { cmdSelect(db) }
            return true
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw RedisException("Could not connect", e)
        } finally {
        }
    }

    @Throws(RedisException::class)
    //fun execute(command: Command): Reply {
    fun execute(block: () -> Command): Reply {
        val command = block()
        val executeReply: Reply = try {
            redisProtocol.sendAsync(command.cmd)
            val reply = redisProtocol.receiveAsync()
            when (reply) {
                is ErrorReply -> throw RedisException(reply.asString())
                else -> reply
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw RedisException("I/O Failure: ${command.name}", e)
        }
        return executeReply
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun close() {
        redisProtocol.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you want to have reviewed in your question.

Comment: How I can do it? The question is about full protocol implementation but is not about specific part of sources. My implementation looks more like Java and I would like to know how it should look like Kotlin style. I have read Kotlin Idioms and Code Conventions but it does not help me on the real example.

Comment: You can post all the code here. Say how the files are named and format pasted code using Ctrl-K.

Comment: I have posted my sources.

Comment: That's better, yes.

Answer (score 3):

One thing I noticed is the usage of secondary constructor inside RedisClient.kt to simulate optional parameters.

You can actually set default values for the primary constructor properties like

`class RedisClient(val host: String, val port: Int, val db: Int = 0, val passwd: String = "")`

And another Thing I'd change is to not use `0` and `""` as default-values. Its so easy to forget to check if they are set. Why not use nullable types instead? when `db` is `Int?`, kotlin enforces the check `db != null` before you are able to execute `cmdSelect`

Edit1: Use private property in primary constructor

```
class RedisProtocol(bis: BufferedInputStream, os: OutputStream) {
    private val _is: BufferedInputStream
    private val _os: OutputStream

    init {
        _is = bis
        _os = os
    }
}
```

Consider this example. `bis` and `os` are Constructor arguments. All you do with them is to assign them to private properties `_is` and `_os`.

You can use private properties inside the primary constructor instead:

class RedisProtocol(private val bis: BufferedInputStream, private val os: OutputStream)

Comment: I agree with constructor declaration but I try to avoid nullable types. I think that we can avoid null in our programs if all objects will have default value but I will think about your proposal.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to avoid null? You could take a look at Optional<T> from Java 8 if you want to avoid nulls alltogether